# SQL Server 2016 : mirroring between 2 VMs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, mirroring

TLDR: SQL Server mirror setup between 2 different VM servers on domain, need help

I have 2 virtual machines, both running SQL server 2016, the principal and the mirror that I want to set up for mirroring

I can connect to the principal on the mirror and vice versa. Both are on the same domain, and the SQL service is being ran with the same domain account.

That domain account has connect permissions on the endpoints created for mirroring, and I can telnet to the port that the endpoints are listening on.

I've restored the principal database and transaction log with no recovery on the mirror

and using the mirror setup GUI, I get the error:

> Database cannot be opened it is in the middle of a restore

Using the SET PARTNER script I get the error:

> The server network address "[TCP:\network address:port]" can not be reached or does not exist. Check the network address name and that the ports for the local and remote endpoints are operational.

Thoughts?

Comment: On SQL 2016, why not use an AG?  Basic Availability Groups are available on SQL 2016 Standard Edition, and are intended to eliminate the need to use Mirroring, which is deprecated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups

Comment: Thanks for the input @david-browne-microsoft, I'll look into that